# awk error: cannot allocate memory

Tags: join, awk

I have two files like shown below which are tab-delimited:

file A

```
chr1   123 aa b c d
chr1   234 a  b c d
chr1   345 aa b c d
chr1   456 a  b c d
....
```

file B

```
xxxx  abcd    chr1   123    aa    c    d    e
yyyy  defg    chr1   345    aa    e    f    g
...
```

I want to join the two files based on 2 columns with "chr1", "123" and add first two columns from file B to file A. This is done using

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$3,$4]=$1OFS$2;next}{$7=a[$1,$2];print}' OFS='\t' fileb filea
```

output:

```
chr1   123    aa    b    c    d    xxxx    abcd
chr1   234    a     b    c    d
chr1   345    aa    b    c    d    yyyy    defg
chr1   456    a     b    c    d
```

However with the real data, fileb is too huge and it returns an error: "can't allocate 6400 bytes of memory (cannot allocate memory)". Could someone give an alternative to do this so that the file is read in smaller parts.

Comment: If the order is not importanta and `fileA` is smaller than `fileB`, try the reverse. Save `fileA` in memory and process `fileB` line per line.

Comment: If the lines are sorted you could give a limit to the number of keys and values stored.

Comment: @Birei i want the information to be added to fileA so it cannot be reversed.

Comment: @konsolebox could you give an edit to the code

Answer (score 3):

This exchanges speed for memory:

```
$ cat tst.awk                
BEGIN{
    FS=OFS="\t"
    lookup = ARGV[--ARGC]
    delete ARGV[ARGC]
}
{
    found = 0
    while ( !found && ((getline str < lookup) > 0) ) {
        split(str,arr)
        if ( ($1 == arr[3]) && ($2 == arr[4]) ) {
            $0 = $0 OFS arr[1] OFS arr[2]
            found = 1
        }
    }
    close(lookup)
    print
}
$ gawk -f tst.awk fileA fileB
chr1    123     aa      b       c       d       xxxx    abcd
chr1    234     a       b       c       d
chr1    345     aa      b       c       d       yyyy    defg
chr1    456     a       b       c       d
```

It uses close to zero memory because it doesn't store any values internally but it'll be slow because for every line in fileA it reads every line in fileB until it finds a match, as opposed to what you already attempted which was to read all the lines from fileB and store them as array elements keyed by fields 3 and 4 in which case it'd be an internal hash lookup for every line of fileA instead of an external linear search.

If there are many keys from fileA that don't exist in fileB then you can speed it up considerably by sorting fileB on the 3rd and 4th fields and then changing the test within the getline loop to something like:

```
        if ( ($1 FS $2) == (arr[3] FS arr[4]) ) {
            $0 = $0 OFS arr[1] OFS arr[2]
            found = 1
        }
        else (if ($1 FS $2) < (arr[3] FS arr[4]) ) {
            found = 1
        }
```

You can figure out the correct logic for that - hopefully you get the idea that you want to stop the loop when you've past the point where the values you're looking for from fileA could exist in the sorted fileB.

Comment: hi, thanks and i tried your code and it did not complete yet!! it was running for more than 3 days and still running. any help to speed up?

Comment: Yeah, I did say it'd be slow. Is that with the sorted version for fileB? How large is fileA?

Comment: no i haven't used the sorted version, i have used the tst.awk code i.e the initial version. I tried to plug in the sorted version of the code in the initial version but met with some errors with the code. Could you post a complete sorted version code, so that i will try and get back to you.

Comment: No, you need to put a little effort into this yourself for your own sake or you'll never learn how to use awk. I've given you the code segments to use, try to modify the script yourself, run it, and if it's failing try to fix it and if you can't then update your question with the modified script and the result of running it and we can help you more. Again - how large is fileA?

Comment: Ok, i will try to fix it. fileA is 30Mb and fileB is 70Gb

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty technique is to manipulate your input data and use `join`:

```
$ awk '{print $3"-"$4,$1,$2}' fileb | sort > fileb2
$ awk '{print $1"-"$2,$3,$4,$5}' filea | sort > filea2
$ join -a1 filea2 fileb2
chr1-123 aa b c xxxx abcd
chr1-234 a b c
chr1-345 aa b c yyyy defg
chr1-456 a b c
```

You can strip off the - in the first column if necessary.  Note that this is not robust, buy may be adequate.  `join` may require less memory than `awk` and be able to handle the input...or it might not!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    file1 = ARGV[1]
    file2 = ARGV[2]
    LIMIT = 1000
    OFS = "\t"
    i = 0
    while ((getline < file2) > 0) {
        key = $3 "\x1c" $4
        if (!(key in a)) {
            a[key] = $1 OFS $2
            if (i == LIMIT) {
                break
            }
        }
    }
    while ((getline < file1) > 0) {
        key = $1 "\x1c" $2
        if (key in a) {
            $7 = a[key]
            print
            delete a[key]
            while ((getline < file2) > 0) {
                key = $3 "\x1c" $4
                if (!(key in a)) {
                    a[key] = $1 OFS $2
                    break
                }
            }
        } else {
            $7 = ""
            print
        }
    }
    exit 0
}
```

Usage: `awk -f script.awk filea fileb`

Comment: Thanks! what is $10 in the above code? And in case if the key columns are more than 2 then what would be the edit in the code? can we say key = $3 "\x1c" $4 "\x1c" $5 ?

Comment: For the $10 sorry I misinterpreted your original code. It's fixed now. Yes you can edit it that way. Just make sure fields from both files would match with it.

Comment: i tired using your code and it gives the same error:can't allocate 6400 bytes of memory (Cannot allocate memory)

Comment: @user1779730 Maybe it depends on the awk you're using. Are you using GNU? How long does it take before the error shows itself?